# Including Capital & Non Capital Letters in Regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm attempting to create an SQL filtering system which notifies the user when the request contains any of the included words.

Currently my regex only supports all caps & I was wondering whether it would be possible to have it also accept non-caps as-well as other combinations of letters for example `SElEcT`

I understand entering this manually would be possible, however, this is not the most productive way to perform such a task.

This is my current code:

```
function checkString($string)
{
if(preg_match('[SELECT|FROM|DATABASE|TABLE|DROP|ALTER|LIKE|IN|BETWEEN|UNION|NULL|CHECK|JOIN|AVG|SUM|COUNT|FIRST|LAST|MAX|MIN|GROUP]', $string
```

Thanks.

Comment: Add the `i` flag to your regex. Did you mean to use `[` as delimiter?

Comment: If you're intending to use this as a mechanism to prevent SQL injection attacks, you might want to consider another approach entirely. This is the wrong way to go about it.

Comment: Its not to prevent attacks but rather warn the user about someone attempting to attack, it will be going through Post and Get requests. I will filter afterwards however this will send them an email letting them know, just a small project i'm working on :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `i` modifier (makes the regex case insensitive.):

```
if(preg_match('/(SELECT|FROM|DATABASE|TABLE|DROP|ALTER|LIKE|IN|BETWEEN|UNION|NULL|CHECK|JOIN|AVG|SUM|COUNT|FIRST|LAST|MAX|MIN|GROUP)/i', $string
```

[More info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html)